# I want to stop trying to log in to Google every time a page loads

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

If the previously logged-in information remains, I would like to bring up the schedule right away

I have finished loading the calendar events using Google calendar JavaScript quickstart provided by Google. However, when I select a menu from my homepage, I immediately load this html, so I run `gisLoaded()` and `gapiLoaded()` every time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Calendar API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Google Calendar API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      /* exported gapiLoaded */
      /* exported gisLoaded */
      /* exported handleAuthClick */
      /* exported handleSignoutClick */

      // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      const CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
      const API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';

      // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
      const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest';

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly';

      let tokenClient;
      let gapiInited = false;
      let gisInited = false;

      document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

      /**
       * Callback after api.js is loaded.
       */
      function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
      }

      /**
       * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
       * discovery doc to initialize the API.
       */
      async function initializeGapiClient() {
        await gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
        });
        gapiInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
      }

      /**
       * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
       */
      function gisLoaded() {
        tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES,
          callback: '', // defined later
        });
        gisInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
      }

      /**
       * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
       */
      function maybeEnableButtons() {
        if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
          document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick() {
        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
          if (resp.error !== undefined) {
            throw (resp);
          }
          document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
          await listUpcomingEvents();
        };

        if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
          // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
          // when establishing a new session.
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
        } else {
          // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick() {
        const token = gapi.client.getToken();
        if (token !== null) {
          google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
          gapi.client.setToken('');
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
          document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
          document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
      }

      /**
       * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
       * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
       * appropriate message is printed.
       */
      async function listUpcomingEvents() {
        let response;
        try {
          const request = {
            'calendarId': 'primary',
            'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
            'showDeleted': false,
            'singleEvents': true,
            'maxResults': 10,
            'orderBy': 'startTime',
          };
          response = await gapi.client.calendar.events.list(request);
        } catch (err) {
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
          return;
        }

        const events = response.result.items;
        if (!events || events.length == 0) {
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No events found.';
          return;
        }
        // Flatten to string to display
        const output = events.reduce(
            (str, event) => `${str}${event.summary} (${event.start.dateTime || event.start.date})\n`,
            'Events:\n');
        document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Because of this, token is initialized every time, so it is inconvenient to select a Google account every time you press the menu.
What I thought of was a way to have `gisLoaded()` and `gapiLoaded()` run when selecting a menu, and then deliver the token as it is when going to another page, but it doesn't work as I thought.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{layout/layout.html}">
<head>
  <title th:text="${#messages.msg('site.menu.calendar')}">스케쥴</title>
</head>
<body>


<th:block layout:fragment="custom_js">
  <!-- Google API -->
  <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">

    window.onload = function() {
      alert('hihi');
      localStorage.setItem('gapiInited', gapiInited);
      localStorage.setItem('gisInited', gisInited);
      localStorage.setItem('tokenClient', tokenClient);
      localStorage.setItem('gapiToken', gapi.client.getToken());

      window.location.href = '/calendar/events'
    }

    // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    const CLIENT_ID = '375633176898-u1u87igf47pntuvjcm1h343am876lqkt.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyCGC5IEURGboI9OmroCQaAlNXUdNtiuW2Y';

    // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
    const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest';

    // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
    // included, separated by spaces.
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

    let tokenClient;
    let gapiInited = false;
    let gisInited = false;


    /**
     * Callback after api.js is loaded.
     */
    function gapiLoaded() {
      gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
    }

    /**
     * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
     * discovery doc to initialize the API.
     * client 초기화
     */
    async function initializeGapiClient() {
      await gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
      });
      gapiInited = true;
    }

    /**
     * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
     * Google Identity Services 초기화
     */
    function gisLoaded() {
      tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        callback: (tokenResponse) => {
          access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
        }
      });
      gisInited = true;
    }
  </script>
</th:block>
</body>
</html>
```